# report error Call to a member function bindParam() on a non-object on centos ,but ok on macOS

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

my code  is:

`$sql = 'INSERT INTO t_account set uid=:uid, pwd=:pwd,` `register_time=:registerTime';`
`$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);`

`$stmt->bindParam(':uid', $this->uid, PDO::PARAM_STR);`

On macOS PHP 5.6 ,mysql, it's ok.
On macOS PHP 7.0 ,mysql, it's ok.

but  on centos  7.3   PHP 5.4.45, mariadb, `$stmt` seems to be null, when I `print_r $stmt`, it shows nothing.

PDO::PARAM_STR should include 2 parameters ,so i think ,the last line of code is ok ,when exec $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql) ,$stmt seems to be null,something wrong have already happened .

bindParam report error:

**Fatal error**:  Call to a member function bindParam() on a non-object in **/var/www/html/sxb/model/Account.php** on line. **479**

my code is:

$sql = 'INSERT INTO t_account set uid=:uid, pwd=:pwd, register_time=:registerTime'; $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bindParam(':uid', $this->uid, PDO::PARAM_STR);

On macOS PHP 5.6 ,mysql, it's ok. On macOS PHP 7.0 ,mysql, it's ok.

but on centos 7.3 PHP 5.4.45, mariadb,

now I get the error reason:

Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active. Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll(). Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.

I wondered ,why macOS is ok while centos is wrong. what's different ? PDO's version difference lead this ?

Comment: You really should make GOOGLE your first port of call. Its quicker than asking a question

Comment: You have 3 parameters in the query and you appear to only be binding for one.

Comment: I know - I modified my comment @RiggsFolly as I seemed to remember it (and double checked!)

Comment: I don't think so, "you have 3 parameters in the query and you appear to only be binding for one",the code is from a sample of a big company , can't be make such a stupid mistake , but  maybe  my php version ,and so on , lead to such a mistake. and on macOS ,it 's ok.

Comment: Then are you sure that you database exists and is complete on the centos MariaDB

Comment: ALternatively you could echo the `$dbh->error` after running the prepare and see what the database is complaing about. It's easier than writing up a question here

Comment: thanks ,bu $dbh->error , i  see the reason  ,  Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active.  Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll().  Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.